# jQuery Mobile Page Bouncing Up Before Reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When a user scrolls to the bottom of one of the "Landmarks Details" pages, (like "African Meeting House"), then clicks the back button the page bounces to the top before reversing.

In other pages within the app, this does not happen, the user scrolls to the bottom, then clicks back and there is a seamless transition starting from where the user is viewing the page.

In order to test this, the browser window has to be short (to simulate a smartphone).

Here is a link so you can see the bug: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B13/index.html

Any ideas? Could this be a conflict with the Google Maps API?

Thanks.

Comment: This is normal JQM behavior on transitions. See [here](https://www.google.nl/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=jquery+mobile+transition+scrolltop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Re_lU7DYN8WH4Aa56YCICw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem without having to use iScroll or iScroll View. Here is my solution:

1. I created a JQuery object that encompassed all of the screen's "data-content" divs.
2. I set the height of all of these to the screen height, minus the tab bar and the nav bar
3. I set the "overflow" css property to "scroll"
4. I added the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` property to the css